# Representing 2d array (matrix) in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, matrix

In forward, I am rather new with MongoDB (and with NoSQL database idea as well), so my question could be a trivia.

I have to make a POC for choosing between RDBMS and NoSQL DB. Most of the entities I have fits well to the document model, but I have a special data, too.

It is a set of 2D square matrices with 3000-10000 rows and columns each. In detail, each row and column in the matrix represents a "position" and the value in cells represents a logical distance between the two. I have a dozen of such matrixes, each for different equipments.

It is a huge data, but luckily I never have to use the whole matrix. All I need is a submatrix of it: I know the equipment (in other words, the matrix I have to fetch from), I have a set of positions (20 to a few hundreds) and I need the submatrix of these positions.

So the facts:

- Number of matrixes: 10-20
- Number of positions (rows & columns) in a matrix: **3-10 thousands**
- Number of positions to fetch (submatrix size): **20-500**
- When fetching I know **which matrix to fetch from**
- The matrix is **rarely change**, mostly read is done
- Read is performance sensitive: **a submatrix with 20-50 positions should be fetched quickly** (semi-realtime process)

I know how to model it in a RDBMS (partitioning, IOT, etc.), but what is the MongoDB-way?

Comment: This sounds like a case for a graph database.

Comment: A simple key/value store would also be a better option for this than MongoDB.

Comment: Philipp, thanks for your advices.
I know that a old-style RDBMS or a key/value organized, or even maybe a graph NoSQL DB would be mor approriate for this table, but this is not our only data to store and all others are well fit to the document structure. This one is out of pattern, but I don't want to use more than one engine, because it would make administration harder and all relations (such as the equipments) will be separated and would have to be separatly managed.
Meanwhile we are making POCs on MongoDB for the problem and I will share my experience when it is over.

Comment: @Balage1551, did you solve the problem ?